# Caching a JWT in the Middleware Pipeline - Identity Server 4 .NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have just read in the [documentation](https://identityserver4test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html)  that you can cache a JWT but when I put the code in it states, it is not recognised.  Is this something that happens under the hood, or is there a newer up-to-date way of doing this as I have experienced a few issues now with the documentation being dated.

I figured I could add it here but I can't:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5005";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.Audience = "stateapi";
                    options.CacheDuration = true;
                    ………
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EnableCaching is used in reference token validation scenario  :

http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html

You can either use [dedicated introspection handler](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection) or use the [identity server authentication handler](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation) which can validate both JWTs and reference tokens.

Comment: Thank you, the JWT/Ref tokens page was an insightful read. So, just to check I understand, it is saying that the JWT only needs a trip to the ID server once to get the configuration, so basically there is no need for caching? I take it "Once an API has learned about the key material" means the JWKs (public key)? Also, I know this is another question, but why would an API need a secret when using the ID server auth handler?

Comment: Yes , jwt token read keys and cache keys to validate signature . Jwt token validation doesn't need the Api secret  , that is for reference token validation .

Comment: reference token need api secret is because introspection endpoint requires authentication ,  , middleware will contact the introspection endpoint found in the discovery document to validate the reference token

Comment: Thank you, my understanding of this is better now.

Answer (score 1):

Those docs refer to a different library to the basic one in your example.

Check out: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/

Comment: Ah okay, so I installed the package in my web api, but when I try and type: `UseIdentityServerAuthentication` the intellisense is not showing anything though I have imported the nuget package into `Startup.cs`

Comment: @user1574598 it should be `AddIdentityServerAuthentication` in the place of `AddJwtBearer` in your example. i.e. it's called on the `AuthenticationBuilder` returned by `AddAuthentication` rather than the `IApplicationBuilder` like it was in Core 1.x